# Sveltekit - fetch 3rd party API on an interval

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to svelte and I am trying to understand how everything works using sveltekit. I used to work with vue for the past years, so its quiet the difference in how everything is built out.

Basically in Vue, when I had a component that needed data to be updated on an interval, ie fetch 3rd party API every 5 seconds, I could just create a function and call this method with setInterval in the created Hook.

In svelte, I figured I can load data before component rendering using the a $page.ts or .js file which exports a load function and returns a data object I can use inside the .svelte component. But now, once this data is populated with the data from the 3rd party api call, how can I update the data inside that data object from within the component itself?

Or is there a way to update the API data from inside the $page.ts ?

What is the way to do that using svelte? I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as outlined in the [Manual invalidation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#invalidation-manual-invalidation) part of the documentation and `invalidate` the URL your `load` function depends on in a `setInterval` in your `+page.svelte` component.

**Example**

```js
// src/routes/random-number/+page.js

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ fetch, depends }) {
  // load reruns when `invalidate('https://api.example.com/random-number')` is called...
  const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/random-number');
 
  // ...or when `invalidate('app:random')` is called
  depends('app:random');
 
  return {
    number: await response.json()
  };
}
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/random-number/+page.svelte -->

<script>
  import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
  export let data;

  onMount(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      invalidate('https://api.example.com/random-number');
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });
</script>

<h1>{data.number}</h1>
```